# Which OAuth version used in spring social facebook?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, spring-social

Which OAuth version used in spring social facebook version 1.0 or 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It provides Oauth with both Oauth1 as well OAuth2.have a quick look at there Documentation which clearly mention both way to use

[Spring Social](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html)